# How to make a dynamic and colorful stacked bar chart based on pivot?

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart

I have a very simple table that starts from `A1` :

```
  ID  CLASS  PRIORITY CATEGORY
 id1 class1      High        A
 id2 class1       Low        A
 id3 class2      High        A
 id4 class3    Medium        B
 id5 class2       Low        B
 id6 class1       Low        A
 id7 class1    Medium        C
 id8 class3    Medium        C
 id9 class3    Medium        C
id10 class1       Low        C
```

I need to make a pivot table (I was able to do that) + stacked vertical bars (I can't figure out how to it). There is only three `PRIORITY`, so we have only three colors. The labels should be centered horizontally and vertically in each stack. Also, there is a filter on the `CATEGORY`. It means that if we filter by a category, the chart should be updated automatically.

I made it manually (see the right part of my image below) :

[image]

Do you guys can show me how to do it please ?

My Excel versions is this :

> Microsoft® Excel® pour **Microsoft 365** MSO (Version 2302 Build
> 16.0.16130.20806) 64 bits

Comment: Have you tried selecting the data and using the chart wizard? Then, depending on the results, you can change the data structure.

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike but it doesn't give my my expected chart . https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrQxc.png

Comment: So how did you change the data structure? as I suggested to get what you want?

Comment: Sorry @SolarMike, I'm misread your suggestion. Let me try again.

Comment: Try to move PRIORITY to Column Labels in the Pivot FieldList

Comment: Thank you so much @Blackcat, it worked. There is only one small problem. The legend labels are not sorted. I got `Medium`, `Low`, `High`.

Comment: I reorder them in the pivot table and not I got the good order. Thank you guys again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move PRIORITY to Column Labels and to arrange the column elements:

Rightclick in PivotTable any labael(Med,Low,High). Sort->MoreSortOptions select Manual and close window. On Pivot, clickdown frame of a label and drag to the position.

[image]

Since i work on E2010 maybe in 365 there is a simpler solution (references from the above image):

- First select an empty range where in the top left cell type =K17
- Copy this cell to range 4 rows x 5 columns (this makes a conn. to the original pivot table.)
- Select this new range, and Insert-> Chart -> Column -> 2-D Stacked Column
- Right Click Plot Area -> Select Data ->Switch Row Column
- Select on the chart bar a Grand Total and right click.
- Click Add Data Labels
- Again right click and Format Data Series
- Click in the left pane Fill, and on the right pane No Fill. Then click Close.

The totals are on the top of the columns.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Blackcat, can you please show me how to add the totals labels above each bar ?

Comment: But it's something that I described initially in my original post and not something new that I added in the comments. If you can't address that, no problem. I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: To eliminate 0 values Format Cells -> Number -> Custom -> Type -> `[=0]#;Normal`

Answer (score 2):

My Excel version is old but this is almost what you want:

[image]

The Pivot Table setup feeding the graph (stacked bar plot type) is like this:

1. CLASS into rows section
2. PRIORITY into columns section
3. ID into values section (make sure you use option *Count*)

Then you just need to play with the format to show the labels, title and all around.

The only thing I could not get has been showing the subtotal of each class (5, 2, 3) but probably because my Excel is really old

Comment: Thank you my friend. If you can show me how to add the subtotals above each bar, I will be so grateful.

Comment: @VERBOSE I'm afraid My Excel version is too old for that feature. You'll need to google for that part because I cannot reproduce it